# Store JBoss (Wildfly) logs on database

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, jboss, hbase, wildfly

Is there anyway to store JBoss logs into the HBase, Infinispan or Elastic search? Or, Is there anyway to create new log handler in my application to store these data in database (not new JBoss module because I wanna use CDI in it).

Comment: You can create a custom-handler or use a log4j appender as a custom-handler. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually, I prefer to use java.util.Logger and unfortunately it's bound to VM itself. Whenever I add new Handler it will stick to Logger even when I remove the application from container. Also, I wanna use CDI inside of Handler (user websocket to send it to HTML clients) and CDI does not work inside of Handler.

Comment: Using CDI in a handler would be really tricky. Logging needs to be configured really before anything else. If there is an issue in your handler with CDI nothing would be logged as logging is not configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not that I know. Custom log handlers are created as modules and cannot be loaded from the application since the applications are not yet loaded when the logging subsystem starts. See here for how to create a custom log handler:

- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CustomLogHandlersOn701
- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLoggingHandlerInJBOSSAs710Final

Btw. why do you need to use CDI? And if dependency injection is crucial for you, you could also use f.i. Guice.

Comment: Logs are very critical in my application. I've written a special component to send the logs with websocket to HTML clients. The problem is, it's not possible to add a handler to the Loggers, so I've written another wrapper class to get the logs, send it to the clients and then call original logger. I was wondering if it be possible to directly do it by Handlers.